# Is there a way to detect Iphone if shaken via javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone

I have an iPhone version of my website. Is it possible to detect, using JavaScript, when the iPhone is shaken? Something along the lines of:

```
<script> function shaken() { alert("you shaked !!!"); } < /script >

<body onshake="shaken()">
```

Comment: Not "shacked", but "shaked"? Even stranger.

Comment: I think "shaken" is the word he's looking for.

Comment: this is a legit question, albeit formatted poorly

Comment: Or "shook", so it would say `alert("you shook !!!");`, unless the past participle is desirable?

Comment: OMG, shacked , shaked, shaken, shook, all same if you can understand them XO

Comment: how do you shake an iphone via javascript? :p

Comment: Chetan, do you read very fast always ?

Comment: "Shacked" = "put in a shack", definitely not the same as the others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my question here: [Handle iPhone Events (like slide-left) in Mobile Web Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733254/handle-iphone-events-like-slide-left-in-mobile-web-site)

Comment: It does not appear to support a "onshake" event. I would try to see if shaking the phone would fire `onorientationchange` (this event works on iPhone 1.1+). Keep us posted on the results of your experimentation!

Answer (score 6):

No, only native apps can access whether it has been shaken or not.

You can implement a native app, by using a wrapper web view with PhoneGap (or other libraries).  Such libraries expose motion events and such through a javascript interface.

Update: I mistakenly assumed that orientation doesn't get exposed through javascript.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Currently, there is an even to detect the orientation of iphone, but i don't know the one to detect the Shake event.

Comment: -1 **Wrong.**  I've seen web sites that incorporate functionality for sliding left/right on the iPhone.  Also, when the orientation changes.  See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733254/handle-iphone-events-like-slide-left-in-mobile-web-site

Comment: Josh, your question is very helpful, thanks! but i think there isn't an event like i said...

Answer (score 2):

Check out [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) and [Appcelerator's Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/).  Both have JavaScript API's that provide access to things like this.

Comment: Those require packaging the web app as a native app.  A random site cannot access PhoneGap or Titanium APIs.

Comment: i think those are to make iphone native apps, not javascript apis for mobile websites, or not?